# Comic about Inca or aztec medicine man visited by alien woman

Tags: story-identification, comics

My dad used to have a comic-book that he kept hidden from us because there was a lot of nudity in it. I would have read it in the late eighties, early nineties.

I remember the story was about an Inca or aztec medicine man who was visited by an alien woman that could change her skin (leopard-skin, reptile skin,...).
She had an injury on her leg and needed the medicine man to have sex with her so she could take his energy and heal.
I also remember she had a golden needle-gun.

Does anybody know the title and the name of the artist of this comic-book?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! You have a nice start here but could you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) to see if there is anything else you can [edit] in? For example, do you know when you would have read this and when it would likely have been published?

Comment: Ah, the old "*I can heal you if you let me have sex with you*" ploy, so beloved of cult leaders the world over.

Comment: Oh no, the sex wasn't the medicine-man's idea... the alien woman insisted on it...